# On scientific merit

Tags: expressions

Someone said in another thread that the following sentence may not be correct because it is lacking "any":

> (1) 60% of academic papers do not offer scientific merit.

Here's what the right sentence would be with "any" according to him:

> (2) 60% of academic papers do not offer any scientific merit.

Do you agree? Is (1) wrong and (2) right?

[Can the verb "offer" be used in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324056/can-the-verb-offer-be-used-in-this-context)

Comment: *to **offer** [little, no, limited] merit* is really "peculiar" phrasing. Avoid it, and stick with plain ***have** no merit*.

Comment: How about **60% of academic papers offer no scientific merit**?

Comment: Why are you so keen to push for unusual phrasing here? Google Books has *hundreds* of written instances of [***have** no scientific merit*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+no+scientific+merit%22), but there's [not a single instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22offer+no+scientific+merit%22) of ***offer** no scientific merit*. If I read the latter from a native speaker I probably wouldn't give it a second thought, but imho it's a ridiculously unusual usage for non-native speakers. It's "affected" phrasing anyway. *Avoid it.*

Comment: You're asking two separate questions here, which is off-topic for this site. They're based on the same sentence, but they're unrelated. One is about the grammatical use of "any", and the other is a vocabulary request. If both of these questions are important to you, please remove one of them and start a new question.

Comment: Perhaps, one should have some merits to offer something meritorious.

Comment: Merge this question with https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/323980/161437 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/324056/161437. I have deleted my answers  to these questions. A few things about you (the questioner, not the person) I found lacking in decorum. This is a forum where specific questions are asked and members who are trying to be helpful give specific answers to the best of their abilities. You ask questions which seem specific enough. When a seemingly specific answer is given, you change the question. One is forced to change the answer to be specific enough to the changed question.

Comment: This happens many times. Then you create a new question asking essentially the same thing. This is not a proper way to ask questions in this forum. What would have been a proper way is to edit your question, then mention how was the question edited below the main corpus of the OP, mention why was the editing done, mention also why the answers given by "a member"/"members" fell short of expectation or your requirements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the verb "offer" be used in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324056/can-the-verb-offer-be-used-in-this-context)

Comment: Idiomatic English: to have merit. Not to offer merit. Please note: percentages at beginning of sentences are written out in full.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are equivalent and both are grammatically correct.  The inclusion of the word "*any*" is a matter of preference.

However, neither sentence reflects what a native speaker would typically say. It is a peculiar use of the word "*offer*" to describe whether a paper *has* scientific merit.

Normally, the sentence should read:

**60% of academic papers are without scientific merit.**
**60% of academic papers lack scientific merit.**

Your friend might prefer it to read:

**60% of academic papers are without any scientific merit.**
**60% of academic papers lack any scientific merit.**

Again, it doesn't change the meaning.

There is something expected that is missing from these papers.

Comment: How about neither sentence?